# Git for Windows: Difference between Git\bin\bash.exe and Git\usr\bin\bash.exe

Tags: windows, bash, git

From what I understand bin\bash.exe invokes usr\bin\bash.exe I guess with some options to help manage windows paths but can't find any documentation to indicate that.

All I know is my scripts seem not to work as expected if I have my environment set to use  `Git\usr\bin\` rather than `Git\bin`.

A new dev box seems to have this setup:

where bash

```
C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe

C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe
```

I can understand wsl being top but can't understand the second entry if `bin/bash.exe` is the one I am supposed to use?

Comment: Use for what? In general?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In the install path of Git for Windows, what's the difference between ./git-bash.exe and bin/bash.exe and bin/sh.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53980686/in-the-install-path-of-git-for-windows-whats-the-difference-between-git-bash)

Comment: For me, _scp_ to Windows using OpenSSH fails with "lost connection" when using `bin/bash` as default shell, but works when using `usr/bin/bash`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`%windir%\system32\bash.exe` = inline bash shell hosted by whatever windows subsystem for linux [ wsl ] environment you have enabled using microsoft store | windows subsystem for linux |  | install.  An alternative but essentially same result as the separate window that start menu shortcut `%windir%\system32\wsl.exe ~ -d Ubuntu` launches.

`%programfiles%\git\bin\bash.exe` -> `%programfiles%\git\usr\bin\bash.exe + some automatically injected arguments` = inline [ main stdin/stdout ] bash shell provided by git layered on top of windows cmd.exe command prompt environment

`%programfiles%\git\git-bash.exe` = windows app [ winmain ] bash shell provided by git layered on top of windows cmd.exe command prompt environment

Comment: Thanks for the reply! As I mentioned my scripts only seem to work if I use: "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" - so I guess I need to understand what these "+ some automatically injected arguments" are...

Is this documented anywhere? Did look on the git-for-windows github but couldn't see anything.

Comment: I don't know.  I ran `%programfiles%\Git\bin\bash.exe` and then under process details looked at command line and i see that it spawns a `%programfiles%\Git\bin\..\usr\bin\bash.exe` w/o any command line arguments so the document i saw referring to "+ some automatically injected arguments" is perhaps referring to internally defined arguments in that exe given its 1918KB vs the bin\bash.exe that is 44KB.

Comment: On my system attempting to running `%programfiles%\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe` directly produces output `bash: cut: command not found` and attempts to use `printenv`, in effort to compare environment differences launching this way vs using `Git\bin\bash.exe`, produces `bash: printenv: command not found`.

Comment: Running the alternative `%programfiles%\Git\bin\git-bash.exe` i see that it spawns `usr\bin\mintty.exe --nodaemon -o AppID=GitForWindows.Bash -o AppLaunchCmd="%programfiles%\Git\git-bash.exe" -o AppName="Git Bash" -i "%programfiles%\Git\git-bash.exe" --store-taskbar-properties -- /usr/bin/bash --login -i` to setup the new command window followed by `%programfiles%\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe`.

Comment: `layered on top of windows cmd.exe command prompt environment` is it? It runs `bash.exe` on top of `mintty.exe` but does it also involve `cmd.exe`?

Comment: @CervEd when i launch & "$env:programfiles\git\bin\bash.exe" and then do a process dump i see no instances of  & "$env:programfiles\git\usr\bin\mintty.exe" running. If i execute  & "$env:programfiles\git\usr\bin\mintty.exe" i get a gui popup that lets me select "msys2", "mingw-w64 32 bit" and "mingw-w64 64 bit" type of bash shell and after that is launched i do still see instances of & "$env:programfiles\git\usr\bin\mintty.exe" running.  So it appears mintty.exe is involved depending on how you launch the git install provided bash shell experience.

Comment: yes, `bash.exe` doesn't run `mintty` only `git-bash.exe`, it was `cmd.exe` I was wondered about

Answer (score 3):

So it appears that:

`"C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash" -li`

yields:

`Me@MYPC MSYS /usr/bin`

and

`"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash" -li`

yields:

`Me@MYPC MINGW64 /usr/bin`

So to my eyes that implies the EXE are compiled differently.

But in my case the issues I was having with my scripts was purely down to the PATH each exe sets up:

For

`"C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe"`

`$ where FIND
C:\Windows\System32\find.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\find.exe`

Whereas:

`"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe"`

`$ where FIND
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\find.exe
C:\Windows\System32\find.exe`

So my script in the former case was failing with a

`FIND: Parameter format not correct`

as it wasn't finding the correct version of find.