# What is the difference between 'git-bash.exe', 'bin\bash.exe', and 'usr\bin\bash.exe' on Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, git, shell

I am creating a context menu handler to open Bash via right click.

My command works with all git `bash.exe` files:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe
```

Each opens a bash shell and seems fine.

One difference I noticed is that `git-bash.exe` looks a little different. The color settings are tweaked. When I first installed git I changed the color palette, but it didn't seem to carry over to the other bash executables.

I think this is because it's running mintty / or as one user explained, `git-bash.exe` is actually a windows app.

There is a question already on this site that supplies a little more information:

[Git for Windows: Difference between Git\bin\bash.exe and Git\usr\bin\bash.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51729777/git-for-windows-difference-between-git-bin-bash-exe-and-git-usr-bin-bash-exe)

> `%programfiles%\git\bin\bash.exe` -> `%programfiles%\git\usr\bin\bash.exe + some automatically injected arguments` = inline [ main stdin/stdout ] bash shell provided by git layered on top of windows cmd.exe command prompt environment

> `%programfiles%\git\git-bash.exe` = windows app [ winmain ] bash shell provided by git layered on top of windows cmd.exe command prompt environment

This sheds a bit more light on the topic, but I'm still a little confused by this reply.

1. Is he saying that `%programfiles%\git\bin\bash.exe` is the same thing as `%programfiles%\git\usr\bin\bash.exe`?
2. Do both of these binaries have these "automatically injected arguments"?
3. What are the arguments he's talking about?

**And ultimately, the million dollar question:**

What exact binary of git bash should I be calling for general use?

Comment: In many distributions, `/bin/bash` and `/usr/bin/bash` are exactly the same thing and are hardlinked.

Comment: That's good information to know. Thank you for the input. For now I think I am going to run with /bin/bash then. I don't think I want the overhead that `git-bash.exe` introduces with Mintty, etc.

Comment: You could check which version they are too with `bash --version`. I'm not sure if that works with `git-bash` though. `git-bash` seems to be running `sh.exe --login -i`

Comment: The name of an EXE file does not really tell you a lot. The question is, what exactly did you install when creating these executables?